# How to get all transactions which belong to a state?

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

I'd like to get all transactions which belong to a given state. This should work chronologically and with REST.

Any suggestions to reach this goal easily?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a "given state"?

Comment: I mean : "The sawtooth state subcommands display information about the entries in the current blockchain state."

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to accomplish this is to instrument the transaction processor so it emits `Events` and subscribe to those from a separate application that can store the information in an off chain DB. That way you have the flexibility to do what you need.

There is no REST API that will do what you are asking. You could use combinations of them to achieve it but it would mean drilling in through the blocks and transaction listing and filtering to the state you are looking to get the history of changes for.